# Linq to find a specific item by guid in a list and return the next 10 next to it

Tags: vb.net, linq

Please how can I find an item in a list and then take the next 10 items starting from my selected item.

```
    Dim AllGirls = db.GetAllGirlsClosestToSelected().ToList

    Dim SelectedGirls = AllGirls.where(function(i) i.girlID = 
    SelectedGirlID).take(10)
```

So if user selects a girl, I am trying to bring back the next 10 grils in the list next to selected girl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in C#

```
AllGirls.SkipWhile(g => (g.girlID != SelectedGirlID))
        .Take(10);
```

I'm definitely not a VB expert, but it should translate to:

```
AllGirls.SkipWhile(function(g) g.girlID <> SelectedGirlID))
        .Take(10)
```

Comment: AllGirls.SkipWhile(function(g) g.girlID <> SelectedGirlID))
        .Take(10)